# tftp from Cocoa app on a Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

For a program I need to TFTP a file using Cocoa.

I cannot find any reference as to how to TFTP a file within the language.

I can tftp from a terminal window fine, but I am struggling to run this from within the app.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, read
http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html
and
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/.

I am not familiar with that theme, but it should enable you to start coding. Good luck